# Without calculus, how to determine the behaviour of the rational function $f(t)= \frac {30t} {t^2 + 2}$ for small values of $t$ ( i.e. near $0$).

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, rational-functions

Source : Stewart's ***Precalculus***,

The question reads like this :

> The concentration ( in Mg/L) of a drug injected to a patient is a
> function of time that follows the formula :
>
> $$f(t)= \frac {30t} {t^2 + 2} \space \space , \space \space \text {with} \space t\geq 0 $$
>
> (a) Draw the graph of the drug concentration.
>
> (b) What eventually happens to the drug concentration.

Part (b) can be solved by alledging that the degree of the above polynomial is less than the degree of the bottom one, which means that $\lim _{t\rightarrow \infty}  \frac {30t} {t^2 + 2} = 0$.

My question deals with part (a), and in particular with the behaviour of the function for small values of $x$.

A graphing calculator shows me that when $t$ is small, the graph of function $f$ is very close to the graph of $y= 30t/2 = 15t$.

[image]

But if I  had no such tool at my disposal, ***how could I know this , without using calculus?***

The only argument I can find is that, when $t$ is less than $1$ , $t^2$ is less than $t$, in such a way that the $t^2$ term in the denominator can be neglected. But that does not sound very rigorous.

Comment: Do you suppose that you will eventually stop editing your post?

Comment: Editings finished , I had left quite a lot of typos. Sorry :)

Comment: It is an odd function, so it enough to find out the behaviour for $t>0$. Note that in order to find maxima you can divide numerator and denominator by $t$ then use AM-GM inequaluty for denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have$$f(t)=\frac{30t}{t^2+2}=15t\times\frac1{1+t^2/2}$$and, when $t$ is close to $0$, $\frac1{1+t^2/2}$ behaves as $1$.

Comment: Thanks José!  Which feature of the orignal expression prompted the idea to perform the algebraic manipulation leadind to such a rewriting of the quotient?

Comment: Since your function behaves as $15t$, I tried to write it as $15t$ times something that behaves as $1$.

Answer (score 2):

You have answered yourself. For $|t|<\epsilon$ we have that $\left|\dfrac{30t}{t^2+2}-15t\right|=\left|\dfrac{15t^3}{t^2+2}\right|<\dfrac{15\epsilon}2$